# How to extract milliseconds from xs:duration?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to extract milliseconds from xs:duration in XSLT.

## Using `format-dateTime()`

XML:

```
<exposure_time>PT0.0032S</exposure_time>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="seconds" select="format-dateTime(exposure_time, '[s01].[f0001]')"/>
```

Error during compilation:

```
Transformation failure: Error XPTY0004 at webpage.xslt#98
  Supplied value "PT0.0032S" is not a valid xs:dateTime
Error XPTY0004 at webpage.xslt#98
  Supplied value "PT0.0032S" is not a valid xs:dateTime
```

## Using seconds-from-duration()

`seconds-from-duration(exposure_time)` return `0`, and I would like to get `0.0032` instead.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: `seconds-from-duration(exposure_time)` returns `0.0032` in your example, not `0` (tested with Saxon 10).

Comment: `format-dateTime` works on `xs:dateTime` values like you get from `current-dateTime()`. You have a duration, not a dateTime. It is not clear which environment you use where you say second-from-duration gives you 0; it is also not clear whether you want seconds and millseconds or only milliseconds. An often overlooked features of the duration types is that you can do arithmetics like `xs:dayTimeDuration(.) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `seconds-from-duration()` should return 0.0032 in your example - except that the precision of the result is to some extent implementation-defined.

I'm looking at the specification at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/ and as far as I can see (I may have missed something) section 9.1.1 states that all processors must support millisecond precision or greater for dates and times, but I see no similar statement for durations.

What XSLT implementation (and version) are you actually using?

Comment: The 2.0 specification states: "The result is obtained by casting $arg to an xs:dayTimeDuration ... and then computing the seconds component as described in 10.3.2.3 Canonical representation." And then: "The canonical representation of xs:dayTimeDuration restricts ... the value of the seconds component to xs:decimal valued from 0.0 to 59.999... ",  with reference to `XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes` which mandates "a minimum fractional second precision of milliseconds or three decimal digits". None of this appears in the 3.0 spec, though the examples still show a decimal digit being extracted.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted, the expression:

```
seconds-from-duration(exposure_time)
```

should give you the result you require.

---

If for some reason it doesn't, you could use the `format-dateTime()` function as you tried, but first you would need to convert the `dayTimeDuration` value to a valid `dateTime`. This could be done simply by adding it to a `dateTime` of an arbitrary date with a null (midnight) time component:

```
format-dateTime(xs:dateTime('2024-01-01T00:00:00') + xs:dayTimeDuration(exposure_time), '[s1].[f0001]')
```

---

Alternatively you could try Martin Honnen's suggestion, but to make the behavior identical to the `seconds-from-duration()` function, it would need to be:

```
xs:dayTimeDuration(exposure_time) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S') mod 60
```